# Why I obtain this error when I try to build a Java.utile.Date object from a String?

Tags: java, date, java.util.date, java.util.calendar

I am working on a Java application and I have some problem trying to create a **Date** object:

So I have done:

```
Calendar dataRendimentoLordoCertificatoCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
dataRendimentoLordoCertificatoCalendar.set(annoCorrente - 1, 10, 01);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date dataRendimentoLordoCertifiacato = new Date(sdf.format(dataRendimentoLordoCertificatoCalendar.getTime()));
```

Using the Eclipse debugger I can see that the value of `sdf.format(dataRendimentoLordoCertificatoCalendar.getTime())` (passed as parameter to the **Date** constructor) is **2015-11-01** (and it is what I expect: the first of November of 2015).

The problem is that when this line is performed:

```
Date dataRendimentoLordoCertifiacato = new Date(sdf.format(dataRendimentoLordoCertificatoCalendar.getTime()));
```

I obtain this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:598)
    at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:255)
    at com.mycompany.dbmanager.MyProject.getRendimentoLordoCertificato(PucManager.java:64)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do? `dataRendimentoLordoCertificatoCalendar.getTime()` is **already** a `Date`. P.S. with the release of Java 8, I would strongly suggest you avoid `Date` and `Calendar` like the plague wherever possible.

Comment: *"I can see that the value of sdf.format(dataRendimentoLordoCertificatoCalendar.getTime()) (passed as parameter to the Date constructor) is 2015-11-01"* No, it's a **`Date` instance** containing that date. It makes no sense to turn that into a string and then pass that string raw into the `Date` constructor. Just use the `Date` you already have.

Comment: And if not using Java 8, use Joda-Time. Avoid using `Calendar` and `Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want this solution, but if you want to use String (returned type of getTime), you have to use parse, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
  Calendar dataRendimentoLordoCertificatoCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  Date dataRendimentoLordoCertifiacato = sdf.parse(sdf.format(dataRendimentoLordoCertificatoCalendar.getTime()));

  System.out.println(dataRendimentoLordoCertifiacato);
}
```

But, I don't know what exactly you want. Because you have a **DATE**, then you are gettin **String** of this date and then you parse it back to **date** :-D

Answer (score 0):

@Hrabosch is right.

However I am assuming you are doing this because you want to get rid of the time part and only want the date i.e. date at midnight. You can use the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2015, Month.JANUARY, 1);
```

If not, there is [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library which has DateMidnight, so you can do:

```
DateMidnight dateMidnight = new DateMidnight(2015, 1, 1);
```

Comment: All of the “midnight” classes and methods in Joda-Time are deprecated. The team recommends replacing their usage with a call to [`withTimeAtStartOfDay`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay--). Also, Joda-Time has a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class.

Comment: Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).